# How to Provide Offline capability to user in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hey we want to provide the offline capability to user how can we do this in SharePoint.We want to give only one form for user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lists

By default you can only connect certain lists to outlook. Lists such as the task-list, contact-list, calendar. 
You can connect these lists to outlook via the button in the ribbon:

[image]

---

### Libraries

You can also sync libraries to outlook via the same button or you can sync documents to your harddrive via OneDrive for Business. In order to do that you have to make sure that `Offline Client Availability` is set to `Yes` at `Site Settings >> Search and offline availability`.

Then you can use one of the two Sync buttons:

[image]